# CSS: Dynamic margin based on element width

Tags: css, margin

I have a web form in which I want to append currency symbol before the input box.
The currency symbol can have 1 character for a currency with symbol and 5-6 characters for a currency without the symbol.

[image]

I am looking for something like this. Notice the movement of the currency symbol.

[image]

I have achieved this by setting a margin of -35px on the currency label. 
But this would not cater to other currencies with more number of characters like 'Dinar' or 'AUS $'. Whereas, it would be too much for a smaller length currency symbol like $.

I want to set the margin as negative of the width taken up by the element.

How can I make this happen? 
I would like to stick to CSS for this option and not js.

Should I alter my style or if any change in the layout of the form is necessary?

Favourable solution would be playing around with CSS and not change any layout or write any js code around this.

Comment: could you please add a snippet / fiddle?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: My apologies. Let me get something on fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gsg16/ckk8nt0b/2/ This link contains the sample. It is missing bootstrap.min.css. I couldnt add it to the fiddle. Once its added, the sample would look like the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

How about `::before` pseudo element?

```css
.container::before {
  content: attr(mark); // get text to insert before .container from mark attribute
}
```

```html
<div class="container" mark="xoxo">
  <input value="00">
</div>
```

Pseudo elements can't be controled from document scope, but you can use attribut of DOM element to provide `before` content as i did in snippet.
To change `:before` content just update `mark` attribut.
For example with Jquery `$('div.container').attr('mark', 'custom text')`